# How can I execute a ReactJS event immediately ahead of other active running events on the call stack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

Is there a way I can force an onClick event to execute ahead of any other events?

I have `problem code` blocking an OnClick event. The `problem code` is outside of my control in an iFrame and script tags in index.html.

This situation is that a user clicks a  link which causes a `window.history.back()` event.  To the user there is a delay between the click and the back button happening while these other events block the OnClick event.

The outcome I'd be happy with,  dump the problem code from the Call Stack and execute the `OnClick` immediately. The root cause of the problem is out of my control.

Closing this. Passing on the message, remove and sort the code.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing a demo if it's possible to reproduce it here.

Comment: There's not really a solution to this - Javascript code can't be arbitrarily interrupted from elsewhere unless it was designed to be interruptible. Who's code is this? Is it a third-party library? Maybe you want to file a bug report with them, as code shouldn't be made to block the main thread like this.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Matt @ScottyJamison.  Was sort of hoping that there is an edge case that can push an event onto the stack as priority and it would jump the queue,  even if I used `addEventListener`

Comment: The only thing I can think of is misusing setTimeout but without seeing an example it's grasping at straws.

Comment: I'll try recreate something over the weekend.

Comment: There are things called microtasks which jump to the front of the event queue, but even those don't stop a currently running task. The event queue just decides what to run next - a running task can never be interrupted (unless, it does something that throws an error, or it uses async/await to sub-divide the large task into smaller ones, letting other things run in between - but these all require the other code to cooperate)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would be a hacky solution and a work around to a the core issue.